# How can I run madge on Windows

Tags: madge

The instructions for [madge](https://github.com/pahen/madge) are only good for a linux system (it requires sudo to get the command line part set up). Is there a way to run it on windows?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out to be very simple. To install madge:

```
npm install madge
```

Then to set it up for the command line:

```
npm -g install madge
```

You can then run it with a command of:

```
madge
```

For typescript generate .js files do:

```
madge -f amd -c .
```

and you'll get the circular report. You need the "-f amd".